# Can't pass parameter to an Azure Devops template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Trying to transmit a dynamically created variable from a stage to a stage template. Doesn't work at all.

**What I am doing**

I run the main.yml file:

```
# main.yml

stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        steps:
          - task: powershell@2
            inputs:
              filePath: Tests/LoadData.ps1

          - script: echo $(foo)
            displayName: read foo

          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bar;isOutput=true]$(foo)"
            name: step1
            displayName: create public variable

  - stage: Stage2
    variables:
      foo2: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] ]
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - script: echo $(foo2)
            displayName: read foo2
```

Variable is comming from a PowerShell:

```
write-host "Run LoadData"
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo]'one;two'"
```

This work fine. Logs showing expected string.

Then I add this to main:

```
  - template: myTemplate.yml
    parameters:
      foo3: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] ]
```

With the temple file:

```
# myTemplate.yml
parameters:
  foo3: ""

    stages:
      - stage: Stage3
        dependsOn: [Stage1]
        jobs:
          - job:
            steps:
              - script: echo ${{ parameters.foo3 }}
```

This time it doesn't work. I got this error message:

> Script contents:
> echo $[stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] ]

========================== Starting Command Output ===========================

/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/5ecfbe2d-20cd-43bf-b6b4-1a4f088d5e17.sh

> /home/vsts/work/_temp/5ecfbe2d-20cd-43bf-b6b4-1a4f088d5e17.sh: line 1:
> stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] : syntax error:
> invalid arithmetic operator (error token is
> ".Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] ")
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

It seems the variable is not expanded in main.

**What I need**

What can I do to make this script working?
Why the variable is not expanded when transmitted to template?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution after a lot of try and it's easy.

I modify main like this:

```
stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        steps:
          - task: powershell@2
            inputs:
              filePath: Tests/LoadData.ps1

          - script: echo $(foo)
            displayName: read foo

          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bar;isOutput=true]$(foo)"
            name: step1
            displayName: create public variable

  - template: myTemplate.yml
```

And change template like:

```
stages:
  - stage: Stage3
    variables:
      foo3: $[ stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.outputs['step1.bar'] ]
    dependsOn: [Stage1]
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - script: echo $(foo3)
```

This time it's working!

Comment: The solution creates a dependency between the template and the main pipeline